# How to uninstall Chained .msi packages

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2016

Recently we added a chained .msi package to our installshield code. This .msi package is created in WIX installer. When installing our product, this msi setup is installed properly. But while uninstalling the main product this doesn't get automatically uninstalled. I can able to uninstall it only by manually going through control panel. What do I miss in the below setting that it didn't uninstall?

The following is my chained settings:
Installation (run time path):
WIX_Setup.msi

Product Code
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

UI Level
Full UI

Install Condition:
Not (REMOVE="ALL")

Removal Condition:
REMOVE="ALL"

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the GUID is wrong. Initially there was a different version of msi and the GUID for that version is given. Later on there is a new version of msi, but the product code is not updated and that leads to the problem.
Once the new product code is given, it uninstalled the chained msi with the parent uninstallation.